# PIG Group - Not able to get multiple fields

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I want to get the who is taking maximum salary in each dept - I am getting the max salary of each dept , but not able to get the name in it .... 
Attaching the file with pig script

```
EmpData = LOAD '/data/EmpDet3.csv' using PigStorage(',') as 
(fname:chararray,lname:chararray,position:chararray,dept:chararray, salary:chararray);
Grp_Dept = GROUP EmpData by dept;
EmpDataC = FOREACH EmpData GENERATE fname,lname,position,dept,(int)SUBSTRING(salary,1,10) as sal;
Group_Pos = GROUP EmpDataC by position;
Max_Sal = FOREACH Group_Pos GENERATE group,MAX(EmpDataC.sal);
dump Max_Sal;
```

**I am getting as**

```
(FIRE ENGINEER,103331)
(POLICE OFFICER,90778)
(POLICE OFFICER2,86520)
(WATER RATE TAKER,88968)
(CIVIL ENGINEER IV,104736)
(ELECTRICAL MECHANIC,91520)
(ASST TO THE ALDERMAN,70764)
(GENERAL LABORER - DSS,40560)
(CHIEF CONTRACT EXPEDITER,84780)
```

**I need the details as bellow with the person name as well**

```
(FIRE ENGINEER,Dudolfi,103331)
(POLICE OFFICER,AARON,90778)
(POLICE OFFICER2,ABBATE,86520)
(WATER RATE TAKER,AARON,88968)
(CIVIL ENGINEER IV,ABAD JR,104736)
(ELECTRICAL MECHANIC,ABBATACOLA,91520)
(ASST TO THE ALDERMAN,ABARCA,70764)
(GENERAL LABORER - DSS,ABARCA,40560)
(CHIEF CONTRACT EXPEDITER,AARON,84780)
```

** My Input file **

```
"AARON,  ELVIA J",WATER RATE TAKER,WATER MGMNT,"$88,968.00 "
"AARON,  JEFFERY M",POLICE OFFICER,POLICE,"$80,778.00 "
"AARON,  KARINA",POLICE OFFICER,POLICE,"$90,778.00 "
"AARON,  KIMBERLEI R",CHIEF CONTRACT EXPEDITER,GENERAL SERVICES,"$84,780.00 "
"ABAD JR,  VICENTE M",CIVIL ENGINEER IV,WATER MGMNT,"$104,736.00 "
"ABARCA,  ANABEL",ASST TO THE ALDERMAN,CITY COUNCIL,"$70,764.00 "
"ABARCA,  EMMANUEL",GENERAL LABORER - DSS,STREETS & SAN,"$40,560.00 "
"ABBATACOLA,  ROBERT J",ELECTRICAL MECHANIC,AVIATION,"$91,520.00 "
"ABBATEMARCO,  JAMES J",FIRE ENGINEER,FIRE,"$90,456.00 "
"ABBATE,  TERRY M",POLICE OFFICER2,POLICE,"$86,520.00 "
"XXRON,  KINA",POLICE OFFICER2,POLICE,"$50,778.00 "
"Dudolfi, Cris",FIRE ENGINEER,FIRE,"$103,331.00 "
```

Comment: provid your input data

Comment: group by position and name?

Answer (score 1):

Ok.. This will work. But Also remember that two person under same position can have same salary and if that salary is the highest then this below script will generate their records also

```
Emp_Data = LOAD '/data/EmpDet3.csv' using PigStorage(',') as 
(fname:chararray,lname:chararray,position:chararray,dept:chararray, salary:chararray);

Grp_Dept = GROUP Emp_Data by dept;

Emp_DataC = FOREACH Emp_Data GENERATE fname,lname,position,dept,(int)SUBSTRING(salary,1,10) as sal;

Group_Pos = GROUP Emp_DataC by position;

Pos_max_sal = FOREACH Group_Pos GENERATE group as pos,MAX(EmpDataC.sal) as highest_sal;

Emp_max_sal = join  Emp_Data by (position,salary),Pos_max_sal by (pos,highest_sal)

final_set = foreach Emp_max_sal generate position, CONCAT(fname,lname) as emp_name, salary
```

Answer (score 1):

You better group the both fields (department and position) and converting to tuples.

like so :

```
Emp_DataC = FOREACH Emp_Data GENERATE fname,lname,position,dept,(int)SUBSTRING(salary,1,10) as sal;

group_data = GROUP Emp_DataC by (dept,position);

tuple_data = foreach group_data generate group as tuple_name:TUBLE(dept as dept:chararray,position as position:chararray),MAX(EmpDataC.sal) as highest_sal;

data = foreach tuple_data generate tuple_name.dept as dept,tuple_name.position as position,highest_sal;
```

Answer (score 0):

--Thanks Nihal Bhagchandani, bellow you menitoned got worked

```
EmpData = LOAD '/sachin/emp' using PigStorage(',') as (fname:chararray,lname:chararray,position:chararray,dept:chararray, salary:int);
Grp_Dept = GROUP EmpData by dept; 
EmpDataC = FOREACH EmpData GENERATE fname,lname,position,dept,salary as sal;
Group_Pos = GROUP EmpDataC by position; 
Max_Sal = FOREACH Group_Pos GENERATE group,MAX(EmpDataC.sal) as SalMax; 
filterMainData = JOIN EmpData BY salary, Max_Sal by SalMax; 
filterData = FOREACH filterMainData GENERATE EmpData::position as position, EmpData::fname as fname, EmpData::salary as salary; 
orderedData = ORDER filterData BY salary DESC; 
dump orderedData;
```